# Why does changing the order of facts change the behavior of the predicate?

Tags: list, prolog, permutation, dcg

This is my first idea:

```
perm([X|Y],Z) :- takeout(X,Z,W), perm(Y, W).   
perm([],[]).
```

When I tried to run `-? perm([1, 2, 3], P).`, it showed a stack overflow problem.

But if we change the order of the two statements, it will work.

```
perm([X|Y],Z) :- perm(Y, W), takeout(X,Z,W).  
perm([],[]).
```

Why? I am a Prolog beginner, please help.

Comment: It might be useful to show `takeout` listing

Answer (score 2):

The `takeout/3` you refer to is commonly known as `select(X, Xs0, Xs)`

Here is another definition - to illustrate an uncommon usage of DCGs.

```
perm(Xs,Ys) :-
   phrase(perm(Xs),[],Ys).

perm([]) --> [].
perm([X|Xs]) --> perm(Xs), ins(X).

ins(X),[X] --> [].
ins(X),[Y] --> [Y], ins(X).
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your `takeout` predicate may look like that:

```
takeout( X, [X|R], R ).
takeout( X, [F|R], [F|S] ) :-
    takeout( X, R, S ).
```

SWI-Prolog has a useful predicate named `trace`.

In first case:

```
X = [1, 2, 3] ;
   Redo: (10) takeout(3, _G477, _G485) ? creep
   Call: (11) takeout(3, _G480, _G483) ? creep
   Exit: (11) takeout(3, [3|_G483], _G483) ? creep
   Exit: (10) takeout(3, [_G479, 3|_G483], [_G479|_G483]) ? creep
   Call: (10) perm([], [_G479|_G483]) ? creep
   Fail: (10) perm([], [_G479|_G483]) ? creep
   Redo: (11) takeout(3, _G480, _G483) ? creep
   Call: (12) takeout(3, _G486, _G489) ? creep
   Exit: (12) takeout(3, [3|_G489], _G489) ? creep
   Exit: (11) takeout(3, [_G485, 3|_G489], [_G485|_G489]) ? creep
   Exit: (10) takeout(3, [_G479, _G485, 3|_G489], [_G479, _G485|_G489]) ? creep
   Call: (10) perm([], [_G479, _G485|_G489]) ? creep
   Fail: (10) perm([], [_G479, _G485|_G489]) ? creep
   Redo: (12) takeout(3, _G486, _G489) ? creep
   Call: (13) takeout(3, _G492, _G495) ? creep
   Exit: (13) takeout(3, [3|_G495], _G495) ? creep
   Exit: (12) takeout(3, [_G491, 3|_G495], [_G491|_G495]) ? creep
   Exit: (11) takeout(3, [_G485, _G491, 3|_G495], [_G485, _G491|_G495]) ? creep
   Exit: (10) takeout(3, [_G479, _G485, _G491, 3|_G495], [_G479, _G485, _G491|_G495]) ? creep
   Call: (10) perm([], [_G479, _G485, _G491|_G495]) ? creep
   Fail: (10) perm([], [_G479, _G485, _G491|_G495]) ? creep
   Redo: (13) takeout(3, _G492, _G495) ? creep
   Call: (14) takeout(3, _G498, _G501) ? creep
   Exit: (14) takeout(3, [3|_G501], _G501) ? creep
   Exit: (13) takeout(3, [_G497, 3|_G501], [_G497|_G501]) ? creep
   Exit: (12) takeout(3, [_G491, _G497, 3|_G501], [_G491, _G497|_G501]) ? creep
   Exit: (11) takeout(3, [_G485, _G491, _G497, 3|_G501], [_G485, _G491, _G497|_G501]) ? creep
```

In second case:

```
X = [1, 2, 3] ;
   Redo: (8) takeout(1, _G451, [2, 3]) ? creep
   Call: (9) takeout(1, _G532, [3]) ? creep
   Exit: (9) takeout(1, [1, 3], [3]) ? creep
   Exit: (8) takeout(1, [2, 1, 3], [2, 3]) ? creep
   Exit: (7) perm([1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 3]) ? creep
```

So, the order of predicate enumeration is actually important. In first case you produced a lot of states with unknown values. It will be a good idea (as possible) to take a list of paper, running `trace` and drawing what's really going on.

But in brief, in first case you're producing a lot of unknown variables coated with the `takeout` fact, which cannot be matched with `perm`.

Comment: Yes. I got it. if takeout goes first, then there will be call like take(3, X, Y). there are infinity number of X and Y satisfy this predicate, so it's unsolvable. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Prolog uses [SLD resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLD_resolution) and thus order of clauses and order of literals within a clause do make a difference. Basically the engine tries to resolve clause heads by searching top-to-bottom in a depth-first fashion. In other words, there is a procedural semantics on the top of the declarative semantics. This distinction sometimes confuses beginners but, on the other hand, it is the key reason why Prolog is truly a programming language (i.e. Turing complete).

Comment: On the other hand, [Mercury](http://www.mercury.csse.unimelb.edu.au/) doesn't have this property and remains a Turing-complete programming language. But I vastly prefer Prolog for its simplicity.

Comment: Because mercury has functions.. a good counterexample would be datalog, no procedural semantics, no functions, not Turing complete

Comment: My point is that Mercury is a logic language that doesn't have a defined search order.

Answer (score -1):

your base case perm([],[]) needs to appear first, otherwise it will keep descending into the perm predicate until you run out of stack space.  keep that in mind for future predicates too, its very important in prolog.

Also, you should probably switch up the order of perm & takeout in the other predicate.

Comment: example code for permutations available here: http://www.swi-prolog.org/git/pl.git/blob/HEAD:/library/lists.pl#l359

Comment: patern matching makes the two clauses for perm exclusively distinct

Comment: @Robokop ah yeah, you are right.  [] won't match [_] so the order is irrelevant.